# No text-shadow in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, css

I have a menu that has text-shadow applied to it, so that it blurres the links. It works as expected, except that in IE10 it completely hides the links.
Only when hovering over links they are revealed, because on hover text-shadow is removed.

Here is the applied code:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #fff;
```

Also, here is the link...the menu is positioned bottom left part of the screen.
http://madebym.net/test/ractiv/index.html

Comment: I see the text-shadow just fine in IE10. Can you open the developer tools (F12) and make sure the rendering and document mode is set to IE10 and IE10 standards mode? It could be that you have switched to compatibility mode for a previous version of IE.

Comment: Yes it works, my mistake. But as I said in below coment, the issue was with setting color:transparent on all links, that is the property IE10 doesn't understand. I served conditional styles to IE10 and lower.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few possible reasons for this problem.

1. IE does not display text shadows the same as most brosers: IE shadows are more opaque for some reason. Then you would have to check the browser.

   IE <=9:

   ```
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(color=#000000, offX=1, offY=1);
   ```

   (Details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
   (There also seems to be a filter named "blur" that might be more what you need. It's mentioned on the page.)

   IE 10+:

   ```
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(100%,100%,100%,0.8);
   ```

   (Slightly transparent shadow to offset IE's shadow opacity. You could also reduce the size of the shadow and see what it does.)

   Other browsers:

   ```
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #fff;
   ```

   (Your normal code.)
2. The reason could also be that you made a shadow using an IE filter for previous IE versions, but forgot to NOT make it apply to IE 10, which supports normal shadows, resulting in the two effects stacking.
3. Sounds unlikely, but maybe there's a default value difference somewhere that affects this. Do you use a CSS reset?

Comment: No filters used, I reset all margins and paddings with *. Also, I reduced text-shadow and it still hides my links. That was the first thing that came to my mind also. I guess a separate IE only stylesheet will be needed.

Comment: Try a JSFiddle with nothing but a white text on a black box with a white text-shadow, and test things, having it open in several browsers. Also, I don't think you need a whole separate stylesheet. A short style tag or a PHP browser detection script as shown above could do the job.

Comment: It is not text-shadow that causes problems, it is color:transparent set on all links. It seems that no version of IE supports this property.

Comment: That's because "transparent" is only in the CSS specification for background-color. Other browsers shouldn't, in theory, have it for text colours. It's a bonus they put. Then try color: rgba(0,0,0,0). If you want to support IE8, which doesn't understand RGBA, though, you can resort to making the text the same colour as the shadow. Or just forget about the shadow altogether for that browser. It's not like IE8 users NEED it for website navigation, is it?

Comment: @Ariane: `transparent` is now an acceptable value for `color` in Color level 3, which should compute to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. Perhaps IE just hasn't caught on yet.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh. Well W3schools doesn't know either. But I know, not exactly the best reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use This `text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

It works here on IE10, Can you open the developer tools (F12) and make sure the rendering and document mode is set to IE10 and IE10 standards mode?

Answer (score 0):

[dstorey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530681/dstorey) and [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1574198/mark) already pointed you to what is probably causing your problem. More specifically, you can search for a

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

or similar tag in the

```
<head>
```

section of your document and delete or conditional-comment it for IE versions lower than 10, since in case it is present it will prevent your document from rendering properly in IE 10.